# GraphAware UUID not generating

Tags: neo4j, uuid, graphaware

I know this question has been asked here: [GraphAware Neo4j UUID not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40971074/graphaware-neo4j-uuid-not-working). Nobody has answered it and I cant comment to ask that guy because I dont have enough reputation. I have all both the server framework and the uuid jar files in plugins folder and this is my config:

```
com.graphaware.runtime.enabled=true
com.graphaware.module.UIDM.1=com.graphaware.module.uuid.UuidBootstrapper
com.graphaware.module.UIDM.uuidProperty=uuid
```

For some reason when I create a node. I'm not getting anything.

This is my log output:

```
2017-01-13 17:59:47.762+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
2017-01-13 17:59:47.789+0000 INFO  [c.g.s.f.b.GraphAwareServerBootstrapper] stopped
2017-01-13 17:59:47.789+0000 INFO  Stopping...
2017-01-13 17:59:47.835+0000 INFO  Shutting down GraphAware Runtime... 
2017-01-13 17:59:47.836+0000 INFO  Shutting down module UIDM
2017-01-13 17:59:47.836+0000 INFO  Terminating task scheduler...
2017-01-13 17:59:47.836+0000 INFO  Task scheduler terminated successfully.
2017-01-13 17:59:47.836+0000 INFO  GraphAware Runtime shut down.
2017-01-13 17:59:47.846+0000 INFO  Stopped.
2017-01-13 17:59:49.770+0000 INFO  Starting...
2017-01-13 17:59:55.480+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on localhost:7687.
2017-01-13 18:00:03.164+0000 INFO  [c.g.r.b.RuntimeKernelExtension] GraphAware Runtime enabled, bootstrapping...
2017-01-13 18:00:03.177+0000 INFO  Running in a single-node architecture (Neo4j Community)
2017-01-13 18:00:03.186+0000 INFO  [c.g.r.b.RuntimeKernelExtension] Bootstrapping module with order 1, ID UIDM, using com.graphaware.module.uuid.UuidBootstrapper
2017-01-13 18:00:03.275+0000 INFO  uuidProperty set to uuid
2017-01-13 18:00:03.285+0000 INFO  Registering module UIDM with GraphAware Runtime.
2017-01-13 18:00:03.286+0000 INFO  [c.g.r.b.RuntimeKernelExtension] GraphAware Runtime bootstrapped, starting the Runtime...
2017-01-13 18:00:07.046+0000 INFO  Starting GraphAware...
2017-01-13 18:00:07.047+0000 INFO  Loading module metadata...
2017-01-13 18:00:07.047+0000 INFO  Loading metadata for module UIDM
2017-01-13 18:00:07.098+0000 INFO  Module UIDM seems to have been registered before, metadata loaded successfully.
2017-01-13 18:00:07.098+0000 INFO  Module UIDM seems to have changed configuration since last run, will try to re-initialize...
2017-01-13 18:00:07.099+0000 INFO  InitializeUntil set to 9223372036854775807 and it is 1484330407098. Will re-initialize.
2017-01-13 18:00:08.797+0000 INFO  Started.
2017-01-13 18:00:09.044+0000 INFO  [c.g.s.f.b.GraphAwareServerBootstrapper] started
2017-01-13 18:00:09.045+0000 INFO  Mounted unmanaged extension [com.graphaware.server] at [/graphaware]
2017-01-13 18:00:14.228+0000 INFO  Module metadata loaded.
2017-01-13 18:00:14.228+0000 INFO  Starting transaction-driven modules...
2017-01-13 18:00:14.229+0000 INFO  Transaction-driven modules started.
2017-01-13 18:00:14.230+0000 INFO  There are no timer-driven runtime modules. Not scheduling any tasks.
2017-01-13 18:00:14.230+0000 INFO  GraphAware started.
2017-01-13 18:00:14.230+0000 INFO  [c.g.r.b.RuntimeKernelExtension] GraphAware Runtime automatically started.
2017-01-13 18:00:14.268+0000 INFO  Mounting GraphAware Framework at /graphaware
2017-01-13 18:00:14.283+0000 INFO  Will try to scan the following packages: {com.**.graphaware.**,org.**.graphaware.**,net.**.graphaware.**}
2017-01-13 18:00:15.944+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
```

Comment: Hi can you specify your neo4j version as well as framework and uuid modules versions. Thanks. Also post your FULL configuration file please

Comment: I'm sorry it turns out that the nodes were being created but Graphaware adds the uuid after creation so I couldn't return the uuid on create query execution. Kinda sad but ok I'll jsut add my own uuid in Python