# GraphAware UUID generation not working while creating Neo4j nodes with Spring boot

Tags: neo4j, uuid, spring-data-neo4j, graphaware

I followed https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid link to generate UUID for each and every neo4j node which gets created from Spring boot application.
Here is the list of steps I followed as per the link:

1. Added `graphaware-uuid-3.3.3.52.16.jar` file to `\plugins` folder of Neo4jDB.
   In my case `C:\Users\Naveen\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Desktop\Application\neo4jDatabases\database-***\installation-3.3.2\plugins`
2. Added following configurations to \conf\neo4j.conf file

   > com.graphaware.runtime.enabled=true
   >   com.graphaware.module.UIDM.1=com.graphaware.module.uuid.UuidBootstrapper
   >   com.graphaware.module.UUID.uuidGeneratorClass=com.graphaware.module.uuid.generator.SequenceIdGenerator
3. Created Model class in spring boot application

   ```
   @NodeEntity 
   public class Skill {
       @GraphId
       private Long graphId;

       @Property(name = "uuid")
       private Long uuid;

       @Property(name = "skillName")
       private String skillName;

       //...getters and setters  
   }
   ```
4. Created Spring Neo4j Data repository interface

   ```
   public interface SkillRepository extends GraphRepository<Skill> {  
   }
   ```
5. Started Neo4j DB and loaded Spring context and tested the configurations:

   ```
   public Skill createkill() {
       Skill skill = new Skill();
       skill.setSkillName("Java");
       skill = skillRepository.save(skill);
       return skill;
   }
   ```

Issue: Node is getting created in Neo4j DB with `graphId` property populating automatically, but `uuid` property is not populated.  The returned Skill object is holding null value for `uuid` property.

I checked [Graphaware Framework and UUID not starting on Neo4j GrapheneDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42553024/graphaware-framework-and-uuid-not-starting-on-neo4j-graphenedb) and [GraphAware UUID not generating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41640781/graphaware-uuid-not-generating) links but couldn't find any solution for my problem.

Please help out to know what I am doing wrong or if I am missing anything.
Or suggest any alternate `uuid` generation solution.

Version details of libraries and tools used:
`Java 1.8.0_131`
`Neo4J 3.3.2 Enterprise`
`graphaware-uuid-3.3.3.52.16.jar`
`Spring boot 1.5.10`

Answer (score 1):

The UUID property is not returned in node creation, but only in the next transaction.

You can check it creating a node using your Java application and querying by this node in Neo4j browser (or starting another transaction and querying in Java application). The UUID property should be present.

Comment: I checked in the Neo4j browser and also from my java application with the different transaction. But UUID property was not generated. Luckily, your answer guided me to find the root cause. In my case, I missed adding `GraphAware Server` and `Runtime` jars in the `\plugins` folder. UUID is generated for all nodes once after adding all dependent jars.Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by `@Bruno Peres`, All Configurations and code were correct, except 
I missed copying `GraphAware Server`, `Runtime jars`, and its dependent jars in the `\plugins` folder. Here is the list of jars which I placed in the `\plugins` folder to successfully start Neo4j DB with GraphAware and to generate UUID's.

> algorithms-3.0.4.43.5.jar
>   changefeed-2.3.2.37.7.jar
>   common-3.3.3.52.jar
>   graphaware-uuid-3.3.3.52.16.jar
>   kryo-2.24.0.jar
>   minlog-1.2.jar
>   nlp-3.3.2.52.6.jar
>   objenesis-2.6.jar
>   runtime-3.3.3.52.jar
>   runtime-api-3.3.3.52.jar
>   server-3.3.3.52.jar
>   server-common-2.2.6.35.jar
>   spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-context-support-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-expression-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar
>   timetree-3.3.3.52.27.jar
>   tx-api-3.3.3.52.jar
>   tx-executor-3.3.3.52.jar
>   uuid-3.2.jar
>   writer-3.3.3.52.jar
>   writer-api-3.3.3.52.jar

GraphAware internally using spring framework. That's why I had include spring jars as well in the folder.

Comment: You can copied only the graph-aware and neo4j-uuid jar into the plugins directories and it will works.